# How exactly structure packing and padding work?

Tags: c++, struct, padding, packing

How exactly `struct`s are packed and padded in c++? The standard does not says anything about how it should be done (as far as I know) and compilers can do whatever they want. But there are tutorials showing how to efficiently pack `struct`s with known rules (for example that every variable needs to be on address that is multiple of its size and if end of previous variable is not multiple, then padding will be inserted), and with these rules we can pack `struct`s by hand in source. What is it finally? We know in what way `struct`s will be packed on modern machines (for example PCs) or it is just idea that can be right, but it is not good to take it for granted?

Comment: It's compiler-specific. These tutorials probably assume that you're using a particular compiler.

Comment: The size of the fundamental types also varies by implementation, and the fixed size arithmetic types are optional, so packing by hand strictly isn't portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How exactly structs are packed and padded in c++?

Short answer: In such way that alignment requirements are satisfied.

> The standard does not says anything about how it should be done (as far as I know) and compilers can do whatever they want.

Within bounds of the alignment requirements, this is indeed correct. This is also an answer to your question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly (just to be sure) struct like this: `struct A{int a; double b; char c; };` is not guaranteed to be padded like this: `struct A{int a; char padding[4] double b; char c; char padding[7] };` or in any predictable way?